# I get an unexpected EOF while parsing error on my magic 8 ball code

Tags: python, eof

I am trying to code a magic eight ball on the sololearn code playgroud using python. I used a while loop and I guess its not closing? I tried to use break, return and endloop at the end and in the middle of the code but still gave me the error. For the sake of the question i deleted the break/return/endloop and leaved it blank for help. Here is the full code:

```
import random

responses = [
    "It is certain",
    "Without a doubt",
    "You may rely on it",
    "Yes definitely",
    "It is decidedly so",
    "As I see it, yes",
    "Most likely",
    "Yes",
    "Outlook good",
    "Signs point to yes",
    "Reply hazy try again",
    "Better not tell you now",
    "Ask again later",
    "Cannot predict now",
    "Concentrate and ask again",
    "Don't count on it",
    "Outlook not so good",
    "My sources say no",
    "Very doubtful",
    "My reply is no"
 ] 

while True:

    try:
        question = str(input("Doesthiswork"))
        endloop
    
        if "meaning of life" in question:
            print("The Magic 8 Ball says: 42") 
        else:
            print("The Magic 8 Ball says: {answer}")
```

Comment: What is `endloop`? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Welcome to SO.  ```endloop``` isn't a valid python statement.   I'm guessing the error is there.

Comment: @ewong OP says in the question they removed code for brevity such as the end of loop code; I agree it could be clearer but that is the thinking here

Comment: I also tried break and return instead of endloop and it still didnt work.

Comment: @Seth thanks for pointing that out.  My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! The issue here is you have a bare `try` clause, with no matching `except`. The solution is to add an `except` clause or delete the `try` and adjust the indentation.

i.e.

```
try:
    code("hi")
except ValueError: # if you have "try:" you need an "except"
    print("oops")
```